# Force 3 Column Dashboard Widgets

Tags: dashboard, screen-options

Is it possible to force the WP dashboard to show 3 columns at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Paste this code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
// Change dashboard widget width
function change_dashboard_column_width() {
?>
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #dashboard-widgets .postbox-container {
        width:33.3% !important;
    }
}
</style>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_head','change_dashboard_column_width');
```

To force 2 columns, change the width to 50%. For 4 columns, change it to 25%.